# Counting the number of datapoints within a Euclidean distance MS SQL

Tags: sql, optimization, geolocation, spatial, euclidean-distance

Have 2 data sets

1. list of 300 geocordinates
2. list of over 2million geocordinates

For each entry in list 1, I am trying to count the number of entries from list 2 that lie within 5 mile radius.

I've decided to use the `euclidean` distance as i am only dealing with relatively small distances.

Here is my code. It takes forever to run. Any suggestions on how I can improve the code.

```
Select 
    DistFilter.storenumber,
    count(companynumber) as sohoCount
from
    (Select 
        UKStoreCoord.storenumber,
        UKStoreCoord.latitude as SLat,
        UKStoreCoord.longitude as SLng,
        SohoCoordinates.companynumber,
        SohoCoordinates.latitude,
        SohoCoordinates.longitude

    from UKStoreCoord, SohoCoordinates

    where abs(UKStoreCoord.latitude - SohoCoordinates.latitude)<0.1 and abs(SohoCoordinates.longitude - UKStoreCoord.longitude)<0.1

    group by
        UKStoreCoord.storenumber,
        UKStoreCoord.latitude,
        UKStoreCoord.longitude,
        SohoCoordinates.companynumber,
        SohoCoordinates.latitude,
        SohoCoordinates.longitude) as DistFilter

where (((Distfilter.latitude - Distfilter.SLat) * 69) ^2 + ((Distfilter.longitude - Distfilter.SLng) * 46) ^2) <25

group by 
    DistFilter.storenumber
```

cheers

Comment: performance problems are hard to answer without knowing about indexing, database setup, and hardware setup.  Can you at least share indexing on tables `UKStoreCoord, SohoCoordinates` as well as perhaps take a look at some of the usual counters in perfmon (disk,memory,cpu) to give us an idea of where the computer says the bottleneck is.  If I were a betting man, I would say disk IO since that's the answer 90% of the time.

Comment: Also, explain plan goes a long way.  Can you edit the question with screenshots and all the info I asked I for?